# I can't use coordinate values in list for hough line function

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

I want to use the Hough line function. When I look at my list, yes, I found the coordinate values of the edges, but when I want to plot it in a for loop, I get an error. Here is the error message: TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("a.png")

img = cv2.resize(img,(640,480))

# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # ret, frame = cap.read()
    # frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
    

    # print(frame.shape)    # 480,640
    
    ycrbc = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    
    minYCrCb = np.array([0,140,90],np.uint8)
    maxYCrCb = np.array([230,170,120],np.uint8)
    imgeYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
    skinRegionYCrCb = cv2.inRange(imgeYCrCb,minYCrCb,maxYCrCb)
    skinYCrCb = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = skinRegionYCrCb)
    median_ycrcb = cv2.medianBlur(skinYCrCb, 3)
    
    _, esik = cv2.threshold(median_ycrcb, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    median_binary = cv2.medianBlur(esik, 7)
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(median_binary, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


    areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
    max_index = np.argmax(areas)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[max_index])
    
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    mask = np.zeros_like(gray_img)
    mask[y:h, x:w] = 255
    
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(gray_img, mask)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,75,250)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50)
    
    print(lines)
    
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        cv2.line(img(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 2)


    # height, width = h, w
    # region_of_interest_vertices = [(width/4, 11*height/12), (width/4, 13*height/16), (3*width/4, 13*height/16), (3*width/4, 11*height/12)]

    cv2.imshow("ycrbc",ycrbc)
    cv2.imshow("skinYCrCb",median_ycrcb)
    cv2.imshow("binary goruntu", esik)
    cv2.imshow("median_binary", median_binary)
    cv2.imshow("Kesilmis Goruntu",masked_image)
    cv2.imshow("Edges",edges)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
    
# cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to draw the edges, then I will try to produce results from the output I get

Comment: Replace `cv2.line(img(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 2)` with `cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,255,0), 2)`. `img` is a NumPy ndarray object, and `img(x1, y1)` is the syntax of calling a method, so the error is "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable".

Comment: Unfortunately I did as you said but this time ı am getting this error, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable